# How to change `DIRS` path dynamically in Django?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views, django-templates

I want to change `DIRS` dynamically.based on devices.

```
if request.user_agent.is_pc:
    request.template_prefix = 'desktop'
else:
    request.template_prefix = 'mobile'
```

Default (`settings.py`):

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'DIRS': ['templates'],
    },
]
```

I want to change my `DIRS` path like this (`settings.py`):

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'DIRS': [f"templates/{request.template_prefix}"],
    },
]
```

Also let me know if you need more codes.

**Note:** I can't use `user_agent` in `settings.py` Because it requires a request.
that's why I asked.

My django version is: `3.2.x`

In simple words: How to change `DIRS` path in `views.py`.

Thanks!

Comment: Settings are global, they are not per-view. Also that's not how you serve a different template for mobile devices.

Comment: Can I add this in `settings.py` currently it is working. Will there be any problem in future or not: `['templates', 'templates/desktop', 'templates/mobile']`

Comment: You can, but how are you going to pick the correct template?

Comment: I render by device in `views.py`
`if request.user_agent.is_pc:
    request.template_prefix = 'desktop'
else:
    request.template_prefix = 'mobile'
return render(request, f"{request.template_prefix}/search/searchHome.html")`

Comment: That would work, but if you are ok parsing the prefix in each view manually I believe `'DIRS': ['templates'],` would have worked as well.

Comment: It's not working well when I extend `search/Base.html`
{% extends 'search/searchBase.html' %}
Template not exist
Due to which I have to write `desktop/searchBase.html `
But when I add `['templates/desktop']` it works
Yes I am ready to type prefix every time in `views.py`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238263/discussion-between-kheersagar-patel-and-selcuk).

Comment: @Selcuk this is not working!